# Custom master page's background Color

Tags: 2013, custom-masterpage

I have a custom html with css with background color - light pink.

However, after converting it to a master page, the background color is now the default white.

How can I change that for SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Try inspecting the site using the developer tools in your browser. Find the outer most element which sets a `background-color` and overwrite its css class in your custom css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe...

```
body {
    background-color: lightpink;
}
```

Comment: and maybe include an !important :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to register your CSS and have it apply after the default CSS:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name=”<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Custom Style/css/yourCustom.css %>" After=”corev15.css” runat=”server”/>
```

No need to use !important in this case.

The CSS to overwrite the default white background is as Tiago stated.

Comment: Thanks Dana. For some reason, I have to use !important to make it work.